# Empty value in multi-cultured site in Sitecore 7.2 rev 140228

Tags: c#, webforms, sitecore, sitecore7.2

### **Hi Guys!**

I have multi-cultured site English is a default culture & Arabic is secondary culture.

I have both versions of an item but when we have empty value in field of type "Single-line Text" it fetches data from English version which have some value. it's seems to be a bug as client don't wants to show some values for field in Arabic but in English and vice versa.

i am getting field values in two ways as below.

```
1)  <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRendererTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server" />
2)  source.Fields["ButtonText"].Value
```

Field have versions in both languages & have all default values of fields like not shared, not blob, versioned etc ... 
for reference please see below screencast.

getTranslation process configurations in web.Config

```
<getTranslation>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.ResolveContentDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromDomain, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromFallbackDomains, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromSiteDomain, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromContextDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromCoreDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      </getTranslation>
```

[image]

**Thanks**,

Comment: Are you using any Language Fallback modules in your project? That may explain why it is default back to English.

Comment: no, I am not using any module for language but an module for creating version (https://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/quickly-create-new-language-versions-on-your-sitecore-cms/) which is not relevant to it.

Comment: Are you sure the context language is changing correctly and that the culture changes when you change the query string param sc_lang? Also check that your system/languages node (with Arabic) is published to the web db. What specific culture are you using- is it ar-xx or just ar?

Comment: @golden grahams, Thanks for your response but i am sure because it shows arabic values if we have arabic content but would show english if no values / empty field value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at how the pipeline is set up? Go to the `<getTranslation>` section in your web.config and see if there are any: `<processor>` that are acting like a language fallback. [Elizabeth Spranzani](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/elizabeth-spranzani/posts/2014/10/fallback-followup.aspx) has a nice article series this topic. See this article on [Enforcing Language Version Out-Of-The-Box](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/elizabeth-spranzani/posts/2014/03/fallback-series-post-3.aspx).

Comment: for your reference i have updated "getTranslation" in my post above.
although i have tested by commenting all processes but still same behaviour

Comment: Btw, the Gettranslation pipeline runs for Translate.Text() method for Dictionary Items, not normal item lookups. This doesn't look like what he is doing with those calls.